# Agendar carregamento de página através do CRON

Tags: php, cron

Tenho uma página em PHP que verifica o feed de notícia de alguns blogs e grava os registros no banco de dados.

Para isso ocorrer, é necessário apenas carregar o endereço ex: "www.site.com/pagina.php", gostaria de automatizar isso de alguma maneira, para executar uma vez ao dia.

Tentei usar o CRON do meu cpanel, mas não sei qual comando posso usar. Se tiver outra maneira de fazer isso, também será bem vinda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Melhor executar o crontab direto no servidor. O crontab tem o seguinte formato:

```
[minutos] [horas] [dias do mês] [mês] [dias da semana] [usuário] [comando]
```

O preenchimento de cada campo é feito da seguinte maneira:

- Minutos: informe números de 0 a 59;
- Horas: informe números de 0 a 23;
- Dias do mês: informe números de 0 a 31;
- Mês: informe números de 1 a 12;
- Dias da semana: informe números de 0 a 7;
- Usuário: é o usuário que vai executar o comando (não é necessário especificá-lo se o arquivo do próprio usuário for usado);
- Comando: a tarefa que deve ser executada.

Para executar “meu-script.php” a cada 1 hora faça o seguinte:

```
# crontab -e
00 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/pedrodelfino/meu-script.php
```

Outros exemplos podem ser encontrados na seguinte URL http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab só deixo uma dica, o caminho para o arquivo PHP deve ser absoluto, assim tudo funcionará bem.

Comment: isso é para linux? Ou não depende do SO. Vi um exemplo parecido que era para linux.

Comment: Sim André, é para Linux.

Comment: Como eu executo uma URL @RenatoTavares? Ao invés de um arquivo em específico?

Comment: @AndréBaill O cron roda um comando, você pode dar um wget na url que você quer ou criar um shell script que faz um curl ou wget na url que deseja e chama esse script no cron.

Answer (score 0):

Vai pelo cPanel mesmo. Seleciona o período e no comando coloca:

`php /home/diretorio/ate/arquivo.php`