# Rotina para validar se data é anterior à de hoje, se for alterar o estado do campo para completo

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-update

Preciso de fazer uma rotina que verifique se a data fim de um determinado evento já passou, ou seja se a data do campo "fim" for inferior à data de hoje faz um update ao campo "estado" para "finalizado".

Estou a trabalhar com codeigniter 3.0

[image: Esta é a minah tabela]

O código sql eu sei o meu problema é fazer com que esse codigo seja rodado todos os dias por exemplo à 00:00 todos os dias ele verificava e alterava o estado.
Ainda não tenho código desenvolvido dessa rotina porque não sei como fazer mesmo

Comment: Opa @LaranjaMecânica, tem algum código que você tentou? Isso facilita para o pessoal te ajudar. Coloca um exemplo do campo, o formato da data e etc...

Comment: Seria essa a idéia: `update eventos set status = 'finalizado' where end_date < now()` ?

Comment: o sql eu sei, o problema é como faço para ele correr esse update todos os dias? Obrigado

Comment: Clique em [edit] e insira detalhes relevantes da sua dúvida, como o banco de dados que está utilizando, a estrutura da sua tabela e o que você já desenvolveu de código até aqui.

Comment: @LaranjaMecânica então a sua pergunta é outra, e já tem a resposta [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44313/agendar-carregamento-de-p%C3%A1gina-atrav%C3%A9s-do-cron).

Comment: @gmsantos Obrigado, não sabia nem o nome do procedimento para fazer pesquisa, obrigado

Comment: isso mesmo use o  cron se vc possui cpanel vai ser mais facil de usar