# Rotina de Evento - PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá, gostaria de saber como que faço para fazer uma rotina que todo segunda-feira, rodasse um método no meu sistema.

Valeu

Comment: Cara.. sua pergunta é muito boa.. vc quer diser sem que ninguem precise executar essa aplicaçao online? Apenas o servidor?

Comment: Exatamente, @AndreiCoelho

Comment: Achei isso aqui... http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://rubsphp.blogspot.com/2010/10/tarefas-agendadas.html?m%3D1&ei=PIjTsrlc&lc=pt-BR&s=1&m=958&ts=1444879723&sig=APONPFmeusfYlq25H2xQS9P9jYiX2phB9w

Comment: Acho que isso resolve

Comment: Até adicionei nos favoritos pq um dia vou precisar

Comment: @AndreiCoelho, muito obrigado. Mas acho que nao é isso que eu quero

Comment: Você precisa de um agente com o cron ou similar, tem uma [pergunta aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44313/91)

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa usar o **crontab**(Linux) e **cronjob**(Windows).

> Você pode digitar **crontab -l** para verificar as tarefas agendadas.
>
> Você pode digitar **crontab -e** para adicionar uma nova regra para uma
>   nova tarefa.

**Formato**

[minutos] [horas] [dias do mês] [mês] [dias da semana] [usuário] [comando]

- Minutos: informe números de 0 a 59;
- Horas: informe números de 0 a 23;
- Dias do mês: informe números de 0 a 31;
- Mês: informe números de 1 a 12;
- Dias da semana: informe números de 0 a 7;
- Usuário: é o usuário que vai executar o comando (não é necessário especificá-lo se o arquivo do próprio usuário for usado);
- Comando: a tarefa que deve ser executada.

**Exemplo**

45 19 1,15  *  * php script.php

Executa o script.php toda segunda-feira as 4:30.

No seu caso, é só colocar o código que está dentro do seu método, dentro do **script.php**.

**Outra opção**

É usar javascript, toda vez que o usuário atualiza a página, você pega o dia da semana, verifica se é segunda-feira, se sim, então você faz um ajax e executa o seu script php.

Answer (score -1):

Se sua rotina for em PHP ou em shell do Linux, pode incluir um Cronjob no servidor para executar no horário desejado.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer isso com uma tarefa cron. Se você está usando uma hospedagem com cPanel, o seguinte link vai lhe guiar com facilidade: http://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Tarefas_Cron_-_Painel_cPanel