# Deletar arquivo no php com frequência determinada

Tags: php

Estive tentando fazer uma função que pudesse excluir arquivos de dentro de um determinado diretório de acordo com uma data informada. Nesse exemplo abaixo ainda não criei a função porque ainda estou tentando entender como se faz.

```
echo "<br />";
$arquivo = 'documento.pdf';
if(date("November 05 2016 19:19:24.", fileatime($arquivo))){
    echo "Excluiu!";
    unlink($arquivo);
} else {
    echo "Não excluiu!";
}
```

Um exemplo bem básico do que estou tentando fazer, é excluir arquivos de uma pasta de que tenham mais de 3 meses na mesma. Não consigo entender como consigo passar esse tempo e o utilizá-lo como parâmetro numa função (porque posso mudar o tempo caso eu precise)

Comment: servidor Linux ou Windows?

Comment: servidor Windows

Comment: 3 meses desde a criação?

Comment: Isso. Será feito um upload para uma determinada pasta. Esse script apenas verificaria a partir da data do upload daquele arquivo para a pasta. Se tivesse mais que 3 meses na pasta, ele excluiria o arquivo, caso contrário, não faria nada.

Comment: Se na hora do upload você puder guarda a data de quando foi feito, é mais confiavel que `fileatime()`. Para rodar isso periodicamente pode usar o [cronjob](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44313/91) ou agendador de tarefas do windows

Comment: Eu já ouvi falar no cronjob, mas nunca o usei ainda. Vou procurar aprender a usá-lo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php) para definir o tempo a partir de um período e comparar com o resultado de [`filectime()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filectime.php), que retorna a data de criação em servidores Windows ([fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4401374/2932525)).

No seu exemplo você utilizou [`fileatime()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fileatime.php), que obtém a data do último acesso, mas pela descrição do problema o correto é utilizar `filectime()`, mas pode ser alterado de acordo com o comportamento desejado.

```php
// a data de criação é anterior à 3 meses atrás
if (filectime($arquivo) < strtotime('-3 month')) {
  // apagar
}
```

Comment: Sançao, até esqueci de colocar a seguinte observação na pegunta: Existe uma forma de isso ser feito automaticamente? Testei seu código aqui e deu certinho!!!

Comment: Bom, no fim o AP vai ter que testar o que é melhor no caso dele, depende muito de como os arquivos são gerados. De qq forma, o caminho pra resolver vc já passou.

Comment: Bom galera, obrigado, já me ajudaram bastante!

Answer (score 2):

complementando a resposta do Sanção, segue código PHP para listar todos arquivos do diretório:

```
//diretório que deseja listar os arquivos
$path = "arquivos/";

//le os arquivos do diretorio
$diretorio = dir($path);

//loop para listar os arquivos do diretório, guardando na variável $arquivo
while( $arquivo = $diretorio -> read() ){

  //gera um link para o arquivo
  echo "<a href='".$path.$arquivo."'>".$arquivo."</a><br />"; 
}
$diretorio -> close();
```