# foreach sendo executado num intervalo de 10 minutos

Tags: php, array

tenho um foreach que tem mais de 4 mil elementos...

Tem alguma forma de fazer esse foreach e ele fazer um loop de 500 elementos a cada 2 minutos??

Comment: [Agendar carregamento de página através do CRON](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44313/91)

Comment: Coincidência você aqui @rray. A pergunta é sobre  `array` :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não respondi pq não tinha a tag array e pq acho que é duplicata :P

Answer (score 1):

DE 500 em 500 você quer rodar a cada `2 minutos`? Utilize a função `array_chunk` para dividir o seu `array` de 500 em 500. E aplique um  `foreach` com um sleep a cada iteração com essa subdivisão dos seu  array.

Exemplo:

```
 $array = range(1, 4000); // Supomos que esse seja os 4000

 foreach (array_chunk($array, 500) as $key => $values) {
     foreach ($values as $value) {

     }

     sleep(2 * 60);
 }
```

Comment: 2 * 60 * 60?  Qual é a unidade de tempo usada no sleep do PHP??

Comment: Tá errado. Vou corrigir, isso seria 2 horas.

Comment: Legal - é que algumas APIs desse tipo usam segundos e outros usam milisegundos (ai seria (2 * 60 * 1000) ) - PHP é meio ponto fora da curva para um monte de coisas, por isso perguntei.

Comment: `sleep` é em segundos, `usleep` que é em milissegundos. No caso, são duas funções que fazem a mesma coisa, porém com a temporização diferente.