# Como rodar o cron do schedule:run no Windows

Tags: php, laravel, windows, scheduler

Criei uma cron que deve verificar a cada minuto se o valor da data final é menor que a atual... se sim deve atualizar o campo status dessa tabela.

```
class SetStatus extends Command
{

protected $signature = 'SetStatus:cron';

public function handle()
{
    //o código ta uma zona apenas pra teste...
    $sql = 'select id from promotions where dt_end < NOW()';
    $dados = \DB::select($sql);
    foreach($dados as $i)
    {
        $updateStatus = 'update promotions set status = "inativo" where id IN ('.$i->id.')';
        $return = \DB::update($updateStatus);
    }
    var_dump($return);
}
```

}

e adicionei no kernel

```
 protected $commands = [
    Commands\SetStatus::class,
];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('SetStatus:cron')->everyMinute();
}
```

A minha duvida é que sempre que rodo os comando abaixo a CRON é executada com sucesso, porém para por ai. No minuto seguinte ela não executa novamente.

```
php artisan SetStatus:cron
php c:/projetos/marcelo/painel/artisan schedule:run
```

Após rodar esses comandos acima, já não deveria ser rodado a cada minuto igual defini no kernel?

Achei algo interessante nesse link [Agendar carregamento de página através do CRON](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44313/agendar-carregamento-de-p%C3%A1gina-atrav%C3%A9s-do-cron) na linha

```
# crontab -e 00 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/pedrodelfino/meu-script.php
```

Mas não consegui desenrolar... vi algo também como criar uma .bat, mas não achei funcional.

Estou em ambiente de desenvolvimento usando Windows, alguém poderia dar uma luz?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No Linux, o recomendado é adicionar uma entrada no cron como é sugerido pela [documentação do Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#introduction).

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Esse cron rodará a cada minuto o comando `schedule:run`.

No Windows é possível usar o Agendador de Tarefas do sistema para fazer isso.

Abra o agendador de tarefas (ou task scheduler)

[image: Task Scheduler no iniciar]

Vá em criar uma nova tarefa

[image: Criar nova tarefa]

Na aba geral defina um nome para a tarefa e para ela executar mesmo que o usuário não esteja logado (isso faz rodar em background)

[image: nome da tarefa]

Na aba seguinte, crie um *trigger* para ser executado a cada minuto indefinidamente.

[image: frequência da tarefa]

E na aba de ações, crie uma nova ação especificando o executável do php, o comando `artisan schedule run` e o diretório do seu projeto.

[image: ação da tarefa]

Depois disso basta dar um ok e informar uma credencial do seu usuário e o schedule será executado como um *cron*.

Comment: Valeu amigo, exatamente isso. O único lado ruim é q toda hora abre o prompt do php e desfoca oq to fazendo no momento kkk + me ajudou bastante. Mt obrigado!

Comment: @hisoka se não me engano pra isso não acontecer ter que selecionar o "executar quando usuário estiver logado ou não"